# subsequent call to python subprocess.Popen().communicate() hangs

Tags: python

In my http request handler function, I need to perform several HTTP GET test with different uris. The code is as below:

```
def send_http_msg(command):
    ...
    p = subprocess.Popen("exec " + command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)                                  
    result = p.communicate()
```

A typical command is `curl --connect-timeout 5 http://1.2.3.4:22`.

The problem that I cannot resolve is that when `send_http_msg()` is called again by the calling function, `p.communicate()` just hangs and never return. I also tried `p.communicate(timeout=10)`, and it hangs also with no `timeoutExpired` exception seen.

I also tried `subprocess.check_output()`, and it hangs the 2nd call as well.

The python is 2.7.3.

Please help.

Comment: could yo change your script slightly (This is just for debugging)

and add  one line prior to `p= subprocess ... `

The line is 
`open("commands.log", "a").write("exec " + command + "\n")`

This will create a log file of all the commands, that you try to execute.

Now you can try to call these commands with `bash commands.log`  and see whether something is blocking even without python.

Comment: Why do you use the `exec ...` and `shell=True`? That seems like a completely unnecessary layer (and a bit risky). Popen accepts an array of arguments directly.

Comment: (...In fact,why do you even run `curl` instead of using native Python 'requests' or 'urllib' modules?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. It turned out that I did not add "--connect-timeout 5" to the 2nd command.

Comment: @gelonida I inherited shell=True from the other file transfer command. Then I noticed the subprocess is not gone after the file transfer command is run. Found people on another thread suggest to use "exec " + command...

Comment: @grawity Regarding using requests instead of curl, this is due to our embedded system not having requests lib installed with 2.7.3 at this point.

Comment: @grawity Yes, I will remove shell=True and exec... for this command. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob just create the log file as I suggested, but without the exec.
open("commands.log", "a").write("command + "\n")

so delete the file commands.log, start your python script. and the try to call `bash commands.log` and check whether the code freezes also without python.

apart from that. I agree. if all you call via subprocess is curl, then it would probably be better to directly use python to perform the http accesses.

Comment: @gelonida The issue was resolved by adding "--connect-timeout 5" to curl after I checked command.log that you suggested. Thanks again.